# Perl read from xls insert to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, perl

I'm am pretty new to Perl and I'm writing a Perl script to read data from xls and insert the results to MySQL DB but i have problem... 
here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('test.xls');
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:parser", "root", "123qwe", { RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $query = 'INSERT INTO parser (Name,Country) VALUES (?,?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "Prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr();

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
        die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
        my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
        my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

        for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
                for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

                        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
                        next unless $cell;
                        my $results = $cell->value();
                        open(my $fh, '>>', "test");
                        print $fh "$results\t";
                        close $fh;
                }
        }
}

open my $fh, "<", "test" or die $!;
while (<$fh>)
{
        chomp;
        my @vals = split;
        $sth->execute(@vals);
}
close $fh;
```

So when i execute the script it ends with the following error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 6 bind variables when 2 are needed at ./parser.pl line 39, <$fh> line 1.
Uncaught exception from user code:
    DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 6 bind variables when 2 are needed at ./parser.pl line 39, <$fh> line 1.
```

Which is natural because i have indeed 6 variables in the output:

```
John Smith  USA Ognyan Penkov   Egypt
```

So the problem is that i cant seem to find a way to split the results from every column/row and put them in the MySQL tables because the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel reads all the date as 1 row.(For example the names must go to table Name and the country to table country)

My XLS file looks like this:

```
       A           B
1. John Smith     USA
2. Ognyan Penkov  Egypt
...etc...
```

My MySQL tables:

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(6)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
|Country | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: When you say "My XML file" you mean XLS(X), right?

Comment: Why are you writing to a file first? And you are talking about a table `Name` and a table `Country`, but you show one table that has the _columns_ `id`, `Name` and `Country`. I think you've got your words mixed up here. What are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: We'll i'm trying to read and insert the results from the XLS file to MySQL table , the id table should not be a problem cause it's auto_increment  field  i need only to insert the name and the country from the XLS file.

Comment: The vertical things are called _columns_. The lines are the _rows_. The whole thing together is a _table_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening a file called `test` for append writing *for every single cell* in the document. You then add the current cell's value, followed by a tabulator `\t` character. Afterwards you open and read that same file line by line (but there is only one line), `chomp` off a line ending that is not there (because you didn't put one) and `split` on whitespace, [because `split` without a delimiter uses `\s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), which is **a single whitespace**.

> If omitted, PATTERN defaults to a single space, " " , triggering the previously described awk emulation.

And that's exactly the problem, because your file looks like this:

```
John\tSmith\tUSA\tOgnyan\tPenkov\tEgypt
```

The `\t` are *single whitespaces*, so you end up with `@val` being all of those. And if you pass that to your query, it fails.

Since you do not, as you say, have a table for names and a table for countries, but instead all you do is put the data from the Excel file into a single MySQL table *row by row*, you can just do that in your `$row` loop.

```
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        my @values;
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;
            push @values, $cell->value();
        }
        $sth->execute(@values) or die $dbh->errstr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've understand my mistake , now it's working properly. Thank you !